# Linear Time-Invariant (LTI) Systems - Solution needs verification

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I don't think this solution is correct but I need someone to verify.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdIy3.jpg) to view the solution

Is this solution correct?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial because both convoution and derivative are linear operators:
$$
y(t)=h*u(t)\\
\frac{d}{dt}y(t)=h*\frac{d}{dt}u(t)
$$